# Shopify list sub-collections

Tags: shopify

Is there anyway, I can display sub-collection (sub categories) of current collection or any collection?

For example

```
category 1
    Sub cat 1.1
    Sub cat 1.2
    Sub cat 1.3
category 2
    Sub cat 2.1
    Sub cat 2.2
    Sub cat 2.3
category 3
    Sub cat 3.1
    Sub cat 3.2
    Sub cat 3.3
```

1. If I am on "category 1" can I display all sub categories of "category 1"
2. If I am on home page and I want to display sub-categories of "category 1" how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shopify, 'sub categories' are handled with tags.
So if you have a product category: phones and you tag each phone with colour, then you'll be able to have something like:
../collections/phones/black
which will show the collection with phones (you will treat this as {{product.type}}) which have the tag: black.
You can also play with vendor here too. So you have plenty of flexibility around this.
[Here you have](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/subcategories) the Shopify docs for creating sub categories.

Comment: @SyedSajid if you show me some code I can try to help. Even more, Shopify has a really open API where you can play a lot with!

Answer (score 0):

Alexandre is right, in Shopify you use tags to create subcategories.

This Shopify tutorial gives a detailed explanation of how to set this up: [Creating subcategories of products](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/subcategories)

Comment: Ahh, just used the same article to create it. Thanksss